# Tar files in separate process using open and vwait

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, event-loop

I have a GUI built in Tcl/Tk that has a button which will tar up a directory. 
The directory can be very large so I don't want to lock the GUI up while it waits.

To achieve this, I am using open for a command pipe and vwait, however the GUI still becomes unresponsive while the tar is running. This is my code:

```
set ::compress_result 0
set pipe [open "|$tar_executable -cf $folder_to_tar.tar $folder_to_tar" r+]
fileevent $pipe readable "set ::compress_result [gets $pipe line]"

vwait ::compress_result
set return_value $::compress_result
unset ::compress_result
close $pipe
```

**Why does this still block the Tcl Event Loop and lock up the GUI?**

Comment: Before I dive in, is there a reason for using the `r+` mode? I'd expect `r` here (which is actually omittable as it is the default).

Comment: That's just what I copied off of the tcl wiki. haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem you've got is this line:

```
fileevent $pipe readable "set ::compress_result [gets $pipe line]"
```

This *reads a line immediately* from the pipe because the `[gets …]` is in a double-quoted string. Changing to this:

```
fileevent $pipe readable {set ::compress_result [gets $pipe line]}
```

Makes things work since it postpones the reading from the pipe until the pipe becomes readable. However, to do so it relies on the `pipe` variable being global. It's actually better to do this:

```
fileevent $pipe readable [list apply {pipe {
    global compress_result
    set compress_result [gets $pipe line]
}} $pipe]
```

Which is pretty ugly and awkward to debug, so instead we *actually* use a helper procedure:

```
proc pipedone {pipe} {
    global compress_result
    set compress_result [gets $pipe line]
}
fileevent $pipe readable [list pipedone $pipe]
```

The use of `list` here does “quote this as a runnable script for later”, taking care of any unexpected trickiness you might have in the variable. It knows how to quote things properly so you don't have to.

---

In Tcl 8.6, you'd be better using a coroutine.

```
coroutine piperead apply {{tar folder} {
    # Open the pipe
    set pipe [open |[list $tar -cf $folder.tar $folder] "r"]
    # Wait until readable
    fileevent $pipe readable [info coroutine]
    yield
    # Read and close
    set return_result [gets $pipe line]
    close $pipe
    return $return_result
}} $tar_executable $folder_to_tar
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it just by escaping the [gets ...] -> \\[gets ...\\]

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
fconfigure $pipe -blocking false
```

after the opening the pipe will help.